# intensity mode in urg_node while using hokuyo sensor

Tags: ros, urg-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node) to get laser scans from the hokuyo sensor and I was wondering what exactly is the intensity mode and what happens if intensity mode is switched on?

Thanks.
Naman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208200/intensity-mode-in-urg_node-while-using-hokuyo-sensor/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In intensity mode, the intensity of laser returns is also read out and written to the "intensities" field of the [LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) message. So for every scan point you also get a measure of how much IR light has been reflected. You can think of it as the LIDAR returning a 1D image (as opposed to the 2D intensity grid for a monochrome camera). In fact, multiple scans with intensity data can be used to generate an image that looks similar to a normal camera image (just in the IR range). The [Calibrating the PR2](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrating%20the%20PR2) tutorial page has a few example of images generated using the PR2´s tilting LIDAR.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-04-30**:
Thanks Stefan!